# how to make a part of the text area non editable in angular 5 and typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having an angular project developed using angular 5 and typescript . 
In my component's html template I have an text area box. 
I want to make the first few characters non editable in this text area. 
Did you have any idea how can i achieve that ?

So for example from my components ts file i can set the initial value, for example : "RMO " to my text area .

The user cannot remove the text "RMO " which is set in the text area.

i have got some jquery code and i tried to convert it to typescript. however it is not working as well. [  you can see the working example using jquery http://jsfiddle.net/zq4c873L/1/ ]

so this is my text area defined in the components html template

```
<textarea id="messageTxt" formControlName="message" rows="6" [placeholder]="'PLACEHOLDERS.MESSAGE' | translate" (keydown)="ensureMessagePrefixNonEditable(messageTxt.value)" (keyup)="calculateMessagingSegmentCount(messageTxt.value)" #messageTxt></textarea>
```

there is a function that is triggered whenever the user press a key down. ie ensureMessagePrefixNonEditable(messageTxt.value). this function tries to replace the old value if it doesnt match the text area content with a specific string.

```
ensureMessagePrefixNonEditable(inputTxtMsg: string){


 console.log(inputTxtMsg);
    let originalValue: string = inputTxtMsg;
    if( !inputTxtMsg.startsWith(this.messagePrefix.concat(' ')) ) {
    this.messageControl.setValue(originalValue);
    }

}
```

however the problem is i am able to remove the value from the text area. really appreciate any help
thank you

Thank you

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/ttwbxwon/66/

Comment: Did you find a better way to do this as you unaccepted my answer?

Comment: I am having a solution similar like you . ie when the user deletes 'Initial text ' i will make form invalid, so user cannot submit the form and user can submit the form only if the validation is successfull. that is a straight forward solution . but customer dont accept this solution , so my manager dont accept the solution , that is why i have un accepted your answer. really thank you for the solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hacky way would be to check the textarea text after the user has finished filling it out (with a blur or on save function) for the uneditable text and if it's not there prepend it back in.

I.e. you have an initial text variable you want to be the uneditable text `initText: string = 'Initial text '` and you have `[(ngModel)]="taText"` connected to the `<textarea>` element. Use `ngOnInit()` or the `constructor() {}` to set `this.taText = this.initText`. Then on button click or blur you check if the `taText` still has your initial text, if not prepend it back in:

```
checkForSavedText(): void {
    this.fullText = this.taText;
    if (!this.fullText.includes(this.initText)) {
      console.log('Saved text not present');
      this.fullText = this.initText + this.taText;
      this.taText = this.fullText;
    } else {
      console.log('Saved text is present');
    }
}
```

Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gg8rpf) example.